# How do I prove this problem elegantly without a proof by cases?

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation

Prove that for all integers, there exists some 
$x$ and $y$ such that $n = x^2 - y^2$ iff $n \equiv 0$ (mod 4) or $n \equiv 1$ (mod 4) or $n \equiv 3$ (mod 4). I used a proof by cases to show that $P \implies Q$ but $Q \implies P$ seems to be way too obvious - can't I conjure any number up that is a difference between 2 squares such $Q \implies P$ must be true?

What is a better way to approach this problem? Is there an elegant solution rather than exhaustively trying if $x$ and $y$ are even and odd etc.?

Comment: What is $P$ and what is $Q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as $n=(x+y)(x-y)=uv$ where $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$.
Then $u$ and $v$ have the same parity (even or odd), so $uv$ must be
odd or else a multiple of $4$. Conversely if $n$ is odd or a multiple
of $4$ we can write $n=uv$ with $u$ and $v$ of the same parity (take $v=1$ or $v=2$) and then get $x=\frac12(u+v)$ and $y=\frac12(u-v)$.